# .net Core 6 doesn't send response based on Accept type in request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I  upgraded a service to .NET Core 6. The old code allowed users to send "*/*" as the Accept header and the code returned the correct response type, xml or json, based on the request. Version 6 doesn't do that any more. The application teams do not want to change their code so I need to know how to allow "*/*" for Accept header and have the response returned as xml for xml requests and json for json requests.

My Startup.cs file:

```
using log4net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using AgencyInterfaceSearchCore.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using AgencyInterfaceSearchCore.Interface;
using AgencyInterfaceSearchCore.Repository;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace AgencyInterfaceSearchCore
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Startup));
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
        public static Dictionary<string, string> StatusMapping { get; set; }
        public static Dictionary<string, string> EligibilityMapping { get; set; }
        public static Dictionary<string, string> ProfileMapping { get; set; }
        public static Dictionary<string, string> RedirectMapping { get; set; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc(name: "v2", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "Agency Interface Search Web Service", Version = "v2" });
            });

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        }).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        });

        services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

        // Add Service/Repository
        services.AddScoped<IHostBridgeService, HostBridgeService>();

        services.Configure<CustomHostBridgeSection>((settings) =>
        {
            Configuration.GetSection("EligibilityMapping").Bind(settings);
        });


        StatusMapping = Configuration.GetSection("StatusMapping").GetChildren()
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        EligibilityMapping = Configuration.GetSection("EligibilityMapping").GetChildren()
                        //.Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Key, item.Value))
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        ProfileMapping = Configuration.GetSection("ProfileMapping").GetChildren()
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        RedirectMapping = Configuration.GetSection("RedirectMapping").GetChildren()
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering(); //enables repeated reading of request
            var initialHeaders = context.Request.Headers;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(
                context.Request.Body,
                encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
                detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
                bufferSize: 1024 * 100, //change 100 to accommodate the biggest request. In this case the size is 100Kb
                leaveOpen: true))
            {
                string body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                _log.Info("Original Unescaped Request: " + body);
                string headerString = "\r\n";
                foreach (var item in initialHeaders)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToString()))
                    {
                        headerString += item.ToString() + "\r\n";
                    }
                }
                _log.Info("Original Headers: " + headerString);
                context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
                await next.Invoke();
            }

        });

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint(url: "/swagger/v2/swagger.json", name: "Acquire Customer Number Service API V2");
        });
        _log.Info("Swagger configured as JSON endpoint.");
        _log.Info("App Configured");
    }
}
```

}

The request object:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace AgencyInterfaceSearchCore.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class AgencyInterfaceSearchRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string AgencyCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string RedirectionCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string CallingApplicationName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string FutureUse { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Accept" in your request header means which content-type you want in your response body,if you setted:`"Accept":"*/*"`,it means all content-type are Ok.
If you want to set the content-type of your response body same as which of your
request body,just try as below in your controller:

```
var ContentType = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Content-Type"];
HttpContext.Response.ContentType = ContentType;
```

And I tested as below,you could see the result:
[image]

Comment: I will test this today and update you. Thanks for replying!